# Replace http and https..?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, strpos

I have a simple php and jquery chatroom for my users. I am currently replacing the `www.` and `http://` strings with a linked url version of them to make links clickable. This works awesome, but does not catch `https://` links. What do I change to make it do http or https? Here is the current code

```
$find = 'http://';
$check_for_links = strpos($message, $find);
if($check_for_links === false) {
    $message = preg_replace('/((www)[^ ]+)/', '<a href="http://$1">$1</a> ', $message);
} else {
    $message = preg_replace('/((http:\/\/)[^ ]+)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a> ', $message);
}
```

Comment: Add the `s` and make it optional. `https?:`

Comment: doesn't recognize the s: https://regex101.com/r/3RYM1H/2

Comment: You need a space otherwise the `[^ ]` keeps consuming in your test. https://regex101.com/r/3RYM1H/3 or change the `[^ ]+` to `\S+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match` function instead of `strpos` to "catch" both `http` and `https` scheme:

```
if (!preg_match("/https?:/", $message)) {
    $message = preg_replace('/((www)[^ ]+)/', '<a href="http://$1">$1</a> ', $message);
} else {
    $message = preg_replace('/((https?:\/\/)[^ ]+)/', '<a href="$1">$1</a> ', $message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked perfectly in PHP

```
str_replace(["https://", "http://"], ["", ""], "https://stackoverflow.com/");
```